# De-aggregate a list in c# Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Given the following

```
class MyClass 
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int Value { get; set; } 
}
var list = new List<MyClass>() {
  new MyClass { Id = 1, Value = 3 },
  new MyClass { Id = 2, Value = 4 },
};
```

I want to turn it into the following array

```
var list = int[] { 1,1,1,2,2,2,2 };
```

I am basically repeating the Id, n * Value.

Is there any easy way to do that in Linq?

Comment: Maybe, but how exactly does the input relate to the output? Where do you expect the 1's and 2's to come from?

Comment: @NightOwl888: Looks like, it should repeat the `Id` `Value` times.

Comment: Yes, it repeats the id the number of time for Value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = list.SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Repeat(x.Id, x.Value)).ToArray();
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w64XKc)

Comment: Could you please give me your mail Man?

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
var array = list
    .SelectMany(c => Enumerable.Range(0, c.Value).Select(i => c.Id))
    .ToArray();
```

Notes:

- For each item in the `MyClass` list, [`Enumerable.Range()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx) generates a sequence of integral numbers within a specified range - in this case starting at `0` and with a count of `MyClass.Value`.  Each value in the range is then projected to a constant value, namely `MyClass.Id`.
- [`Enumerable.SelectMany()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) is then used to flatten the enumerable of constant values into a single list.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/D8K3ib).

Comment: This is one of the rare cases where i like `Repeat` more. Because it works(value type) and is exactly what OP wants to do. So it's more readable and  more concise.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - yes, I think I agree.  I use it so rarely that it slipped my mind.  But both work fine.